Lorentz transformation and Minkowski geometry
Considering what I have studied so far, I don't fully understand why the components of the Minkowski metric are defined such that $e_x*e_x =-1$ or $e_t*e_t =-1$. While I understand that the Lorentz transformation preserves the speed of light, I'm unclear on why this results in the invariance of the spacetime interval $S^2 = ct^2 - x^2$. Is this invariance related to Noether's theorem in any way? Could you please explain why the spacetime interval remains invariant under Lorentz transformations within the context of the Minkowski metric?

what have you tried so far?
